# What's the Akka-typed equivalent to pipeTo?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I'm currently trying to rewrite an existing untyped actor into a typed one. Since the actor is talking to a MySQL database using ScalikeJDBC, and since I'd like to have that done asynchronously, I'm dealing with Futures coming out of a separate (non-actor) repository class.

With untyped Akka, in an actor's receive method, I could do this:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe
val horseList : Future[Seq[Horse]] = horseRepository.listHorses(...)
horseList pipeTo sender()
```

And the sender actor would eventually receive a list of horses. I can't figure out how to do this inside a Behaviour, like:

```
val behaviour : Behavior[ListHorses] = Behaviors.receive { 
    (ctx,msg) => msg match {
        case ListHorses(replyTo) => 
            val horseListF : Future[Seq[Horse]] = horseRepository.listHorses(...)
            // -> how do I make horseListF's content end up at replyTo? <-
            Behaviors.same
    }
}
```

The pipe pattern doesn't work (as it expects an untyped ActorRef), and so far I haven't found anything else in the `akka-actor-typed` (2.5.12) dependency I'm using to make this work.

How do I do this?

Comment: how can you be sure that another message from another "sender" hasn´t arrived to the mailbox in your sample. If that was the case you would be sending the database response to a wrong client

Comment: As far as I know, sender() is guaranteed to be the sender of the current message for any single invocation of receive(), which as described is where the sample code would live.

Answer (score 3):

In Akka 2.5.22 (maybe earlier) there is `context.pipeToSelf`:

```
  def pipeToSelf[Value](future: Future[Value])(mapResult: Try[Value] => T): Unit
```

You still have to provide a pattern match for `Success` and `Failure`, which in my code I've reduced with this sugar:

```
def mapPipe[A, T](success: A => T, failure: Throwable => T): Try[A] => T = {
  case Success(value) => success(value)
  case Failure(e) => failure(e)
}
```

Resulting in a call like this:

```
case class Horses(horses: Seq[Horse]) extends Command
case class HorseFailure(e: Throwable) extends Command

...

context.pipeToSelf(horseList) {
  mapPipe(Horses,HorseFailure)
}
```

Comment: This is descried in details on the official doc: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#send-future-result-to-self

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send a message to `replyTo` when the future completes successfully:

```
case ListHorses(replyTo) => 
    horseRepository.listHorses(...) foreach { horses => replyTo ! horses }
    Behaviors.same
```

Or if you want to handle errors as well:

```
case ListHorses(replyTo) =>
    horseRepository.listHorses(...) onComplete { 
        case Success(horses) => replyTo ! horses
        case Failure(e) => // error handling 
    }
    Behaviors.same
```

In order for this to work, you need an `ExecutionContext`. It usually makes sense to use the same one as the actor, so you will have to make it available to `onComplete` or `foreach` first:

```
implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
```

Comment: This is wrong because it breaks the actor encapsulation model. Messages sent from the onComplete callback are sent from a thread that is (likely) different from the one that executes the actor.